# Gunzip from string

Tags: linux, bash, escaping, gzip, gunzip

I have one problem. I'd like to decompress string directly from a file. I have one script in bash that create another script.

```
#!/bin/bash


echo -n '#!/bin/bash 
' > test.sh #generate header for interpreter
echo -n "echo '" >> test.sh #print echo to file
echo -n "My name is Daniel" | gzip -f >> test.sh #print encoded by gzip string into a file
echo -n "' | gunzip;" >> test.sh #print reverse commands for decode into a file
chmod a+x test.sh #make file executable
```

I want to generate script test.sh that will the shortest script. I'm trying to compress string "My name is Daniel" and write it directly into file test.sh

But if I run test.sh i got gzip: stdin has flags 0x81 -- not supported
Do you know why have I got this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gzip output is binary so it can contain any character, as script is generated with bash it contains characters which are encoded (`echo $LANG`).

characters which cause problem between single quotes are `NUL 0x0`, `' 0x27` and non ascii characters 128-256 `0x80-0xff`.

a solution can be to use ANSI C quotes `$'..'` and to escape NUL and non ascii characters.

EDIT bash string can't contain nul character :

```
gzip -c <<<"My name is Daniel" | od -c -tx1
```

trying to create ansi string

```
echo -n $'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\xf7i\xe2Y\x00\x03\xf3\xadT\xc8K\xccMU\xc8,VpI\xcc\xcbL\xcd\^C1\x00\xa5u\x87\xad\x11\x00\x00\x00' | od -c -tx1
```

shows that string is truncated after nul character.

The best compromise may be to use base64 encoding:

```
gzip <<<"My name is Daniel"| base64

base64 --decode <<__END__ | gzip -cd
H4sIAPts4lkAA/OtVMhLzE1VyCxWcEnMy0zN4QIAgdbGlBIAAAA=
__END__
```

or

```
base64 --decode <<<H4sIAPts4lkAA/OtVMhLzE1VyCxWcEnMy0zN4QIAgdbGlBIAAAA=|gzip -cd
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with storing null character (\0) in bash script.
Null character can not be stored in echo and variable string. It can be stored in files and pipes.

I want to avoid use base64, but I fixed it with

```
printf "...%b....%b" "\0" "\0"
```

I edited script with bless hex editor. It's working for me :)